# WAV is not getting played in Android mobile Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, audio

I've got Chrome version 47.0 in my Android mobile and I'm getting an audio byte stream response (in audio/wav format) from a JSP and that needs to be played in Chrome browser.

It's working fine in Desktop Chrome (which has version 37) but failing in Android mobile Chrome 47 (nothing happened when I click on play button in audio control). Also, for test sake, I made a change to the servlet to return audio bytes as an attachment (ContentType) and it got played well in VLC which confirms no issue with audio byte stream.

Please note am not trying anything here for audio auto play.

Comment: Probably not supported on mobile. Also, sending uncompressed audio is generally a waste of bandwidth, especially for mobile.

Comment: Is there any way to trace whats happening?

Comment: Wondering why audio tag isn't working (even after user gesture) in android chrome :-( this is making me insane. any help?

Comment: Since you're generating the content yourself with JSP rather than using a standard static-content server, my guess would be you're not supporting Range requests. This can cause media playback to fail on some browsers.